# WPF: Shared Size in Custom Panel?

Tags: wpf, panel, measure

Im trying to implement something similar to SharedSizeGroup in Column/RowDefinition for Grids.

Simplified case:

```
<l:MyCustomPanel>
  <l:MyCustomPanel>
    <TextBlock l:MyCustomPanel.SharedWidth="t1" />
  </l:MyCustomPanel>
  <l:MyCustomPanel>
    <TextBlock l:MyCustomPanel.SharedWidth="t1" />
  </l:MyCustomPanel>
</l:MyCustomPanel>
```

The root-panel is defining the scope. All elements with the same SharedWidth should have the same width. I have implemented my custom Measure and Arrange-behaviours but Im struggling to get it to work with the SharedSize-model. I suspect I have to make two passes of the arrange-process somehow? First one to find out the default-sizes (and gather the max width) and then one more pass to use this max width as a parameter in the arrange-result. But how would I do this? I guess I cant run two passes in each ArrangeOverride because this would case every element to make two passes of its entire tree of descending elements? Hmmmmm. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

This code illustrates the problem more in detail:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Children[0].Measure(availableSize);
        return Children[0].DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Children[0].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), new Size(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height)));
        return finalSize;
    }
}

<StackPanel>
  <l:CustomPanel>
    <TextBox />
  </l:CustomPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

When entering text in the textbox making it overflow, it expands into space made unavailable...

Answer (score 2):

As luck would have it, those two passes of the entire tree are already built into the layout system.  First collect all the natural sizes during the `MeasureOverride` pass, and then use that information during the `ArrangeOverride` pass to choose the shared width values.

Comment: Ahhh I see. But since the available space passed to Measure on each children is changed in Arrange (when the gathered max values are available), it seem like elements is still behaving as if they had all that space they initialy was given, but clipped. Textboxes are for instance expanding outside the arrange-rect as if they had more space to expand into. How could that be solved?

Comment: During the arrange pass, you know both the desired width of the text block and the computed shared width of the text block, which should be larger.  You are in charge: just set the final rect of the text block to include the shared width and the text block will comply.

Comment: The textbox is not complying in my code, but Im probably making something wrong... I updated this post with some code.

Comment: First you have to remember that each time you type a character into the text box, it results in another pair of measure and arrange passes.  Second, if the final size you assign to it during arrange is smaller than the desired size during measure, it will be clipped.  In that case you have to force a new layout with `UpdateLayout`, this time giving it a smaller available size during measure.

Comment: Ok, so to make a "shared size"-behaviour I would have to do two measure passes (measure->arrange->measure->arrange)? Its to bad the final size provided in arrange isnt used for more than rendering.